# Restore .bak file to MSSQL using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I've run into a brick wall. I have tried various forms and troubleshooting through permissions etc. Ultimately, I am attempting to restore a .bak file to MSSQL using python. I can restore manually via MS Server Management Studio, however, I would like to automate the restore and drop functionality so I can run through a series of databases to execute queries.

- Python 3.11.5 via Anaconda environment
- Jupyter Notebook
- User experience is nominal

I have researched this at length and cannot find a resolution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code with returns;

```
import pyodbc

server_name = 'DESKTOP-OEBL7M5\\FYRE'
database_name = 'shell'
target_database_name = 'Hoosker_Doo_6H'
windows_authentication = True
username = 'DESKTOP-OEBL7M5\\BKR'
password = None
backup_file_path = 'C:\\Database\\Raw Data Files\\New Database Files'

if windows_authentication:
    conn_str = f'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={server_name};DATABASE={database_name};Trusted_Connection=yes;'
else:
    conn_str = f'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={server_namer};DATABASE={database_name};UID={username};PWD={password}'

try:
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

restore_query = f'''
RESTORE DATABASE {target_database_name}
FROM DISK = '{backup_file_path}'
WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY;
'''

try:
    conn.autocommit = True
    cursor.execute(restore_query)
    print(f"Databse '{target_database_name}' restored successfully!")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
finally:
    conn.autocommit = False
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

> Error: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open backup device 'C:\Database\Raw Data Files\New Database Files'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.). (3201) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (3013)")

Comment: Don't forget `RESTORE` paths are relative to the SQL Server *host*, not your local machine, and the service account SQL Server is running under requires access to the path the backup is located in.

Comment: Also don't inject database and filenames into the query, use parameters like `RESTORE DATABASE @db FROM DISK = @file`

Comment: @ThomA I ran the 'SELECT HOST_NAME()' command in MSSMS and it returned 'DESKTOP-OEBL7M5'. I have also granted full permissions to the backup path under the 'Shared' and 'Advanced Sharing' configurations so that 'Everyone' has full read/write capabilities.

Comment: @Charlieface I'm a little confused - how should I write the restore_query then?

Comment: Like I said, using parameters, and you pass the parameters in separately through `cursor.execute`. *"I have also granted full permissions to the backup path under the 'Shared' and 'Advanced Sharing'"* is it on a network share? If not then that is irrelevant. You need to go to the Security tab and give the service account permission to read the files. If it's on a network share then it's impossible unless you enable Guest/Anonymous login which is dangerous, or you use a gMSA account from your Active Directory (which it sounds like you don't have).

Comment: What happens if you set `backup_file_path` to the full path of a .bak file instead of a folder?

Answer (score 1):

I think you had a typo in your code in line below:

`conn_str = f'DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER={server_namer};DATABASE={database_name};UID={username};PWD={password}'`

replace `'server_namer'` with `'server_name'` and rest of code is fine.

Best